# Wordpress Image Aspect Ratio

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, portfolio

I have an portfolio webpage, my problem is how can I adjust the image position when the image is bigger and smaller, for example I have a image that is vertically long and I have a image that is only small. how do I make the long image to be position as top while keeping the small image as centered.

I used a acf image uploader
Source Code:

```
<?php if( get_field('image_thumbnail') ): ?>
    <div class="image__thumbnails" style="background-image: url(<?php the_field('image_thumbnail'); ?>);background-position: top;background-size: 100%;background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
    <!--    <img src="<?php the_field('image_thumbnail'); ?>" />-->
<?php endif; ?>
```

## css

```
.image__thumbnails {
    height: 212px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try css property:

```
.image__thumbnails{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    object-fit:cover;
    }
```

also :

```
object-fit: contain,cover,fill, etc...;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper
{
   display:flex;
    /* align-items:center; this doesn't works in ie11 */
}

.wrapper > *
{
   align-self:center; /* this works in ie11 */
}
```